# javaScript - guess tiles game

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making an javaScript game - that in the end is going to be a battleship game with grid GUI and so forth.

Have started making a horizontal grid with tiles (that the user can define for himself(min. 4 tiles))

When clicked a tile turns from blue to red indicating if it has been hit or not - BUT it doesn't register that if it is hit 3 times then the stats and accuracy should pop-up:

etc. after 3 this it will pop-up with stats: "You took 3-4 guesses to sink my battleship and your accuracy is 30%"

Instead it gives me 0 guesses and my accuracy is infinity :)

I have posted my code below:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
    td 
    {
        width: 94px;
        height: 94px;
        background-color: blue;
    }


    .clicked
{
    color: red;
}



    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="board">
<div id="messageArea"></div>
<table>
<tr id="tblRow">
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

var boardLength;

do {

boardLength = prompt('Enter length of board length (min 4)')
}

while(boardLength <4);

var boardLengthCal = parseInt(boardLength)-2;
var randomLoc = Math.floor(Math.random() * boardLengthCal);
var location1 = randomLoc;
var location2 = location1 + 1;
var location3 = location1 + 2;
console.log(location1);
console.log(location2);
console.log(location3);



for (var i = 0; i < boardLength; i++){
document.getElementById('tblRow').innerHTML +="<td id='"+i+"'></td>"
};

var fields = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
for (var i =0; i < fields.length; i++){
fields[i].addEventListener('click', pickLocation)
};

function pickLocation(){

guess = this.id;
    if (guess < 0 || guess > boardLength) {
        alert("Please enter a valid cell number!");
    } else {
        guesses = guesses + 1;
        if (guess == location1 || guess == location2 || guess == location3) {
            changeColor(this, "red");
            alert("HIT!");
            hits = hits + 1;
            if (hits == 3) {
                isSunk = true;
                alert("You sank my battleship!");
            }
        } else {
            alert("MISS");
        }



        }

}

var guess;
var hits = 0;
var guesses = 0;
var isSunk = false;

var stats = "You took " + guesses + " guesses to sink the battleship, " +
            "which means your shooting accuracy was " + (3*100/guesses)+"%";
alert(stats);


function changeColor(element, color)
{
    element.style.backgroundColor = color;
};

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `stats` is being computed with 300 divided by 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stats showing code is executing before the game even started. At that time value of your guesses is 0, so dividing by 0 is giving you infinity. You need to put your stats code in a function and call it when the game ends (3 hits)

```
function stats(){
    var stats = "You took " + guesses + " guesses to sink the battleship, " +
            "which means your shooting accuracy was " + (3*100/guesses)+"%";
    alert(stats);
}

if (hits == 3) {
   isSunk = true;
   alert("You sank my battleship!");
   stats();
}
```

Now when the user hits three time, only then stats will pop up with correct values.

**[See the DMEO here](http://jsfiddle.net/xw1Lug12/)**

*EDIT:*
I made some improvements in your game and now really made it playable by introducing random numbers instead of three in a line and other minor errors removed.. you can check that version **[HERE.](http://jsfiddle.net/xw1Lug12/1/)**

Comment: Thanks a lot Abdul.. works like a dream - while try to add GUI with grid and ships will maybe write if i stumble upon problems

Comment: You're always welcome, don't forget to give me a free copy of the game (: